# Keyboard shortcut in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want this dialogue box to appear when i press (ctrl+.)when importing a library class. see the image
[image: importing library class]

But instead I am getting this dialogue box see the image

[image: namespace not found]

Comment: You need to add a reference to your project. It doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: i added the reference but i am not getting that dialogue box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason seems to be that Store class is in some other project that you have not referenced. Check your references, add it if it's missing and the shortcut should work as expected after that.

Comment: thanks sachin i removed the reference and re added now error got resolved.